# Click link on load with jQuery

Tags: jquery, onload

Here's a contrived example of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1"/>    
        <title></title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" class="foo">YahOO</a>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#foo").trigger('click');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have the link fired immediately upon page load. The above does not work and is incorrect? How could this be done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have the class `foo` set on your element, not an `id` so you need to use `.foo`. Also, as @JusticeErolin pointed out, the document ready handler doesn't need quotes. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".foo").trigger('click');
});
```

For reference, `$("#foo")` will look for an element with `id="foo"`, of which there should only ever be one in your page as ids should be unique.

`$(".foo")` will look for elements with `class="foo"`, of which you can have as many as you like.

Comment: Also, use $(document) without quotes.

Comment: <body>
  <div>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="foo">YahOO</a>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".foo").trigger('click');
  });
  </script>
  </body>
     
     
This should work now? If not...???

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what the poster seems to be trying to do is open the url "http://www.google.com" on page load. What $(".foo").trigger('click'); does is fire all the jQuery click-eventlisteners that are binded to the foo-class. Although your answer is correct, I must state that what he seems to be trying to do will not work this way. (He could try faking it with adding a click-eventlistener to the elements with the foo-class and using window.location.href = url. (Although I cannot think of one single use for this weird way to redirect.))

Comment: Hm. Could you explain what you're really trying to do when the user visits the page? What should happen exactly?

Comment: A user clicks a link on page A. This opens up a new window (popup) page B (window.open + document.write function). Page A then "auto" clicks a specific link on page B. Note this link (a href) has underlying javascript associated with it. Do not ask about the logic of why, it just is unfortunately...

Comment: The above answers were correct. I needed binding for one part as well click for the other.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many options, but I found one option which worked for me :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#upload-file')[0].click(function(){
     }); 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to wait until controls are loaded on the page

add this to the bottom on the page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("#whateverElement").click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: It was not the problem, because jQuery's ready functionality will wait for the page to load completely. It is neither necessary to place the JS code at the end of the page. Read the accepted answer.